# Update a list on filter

Tags: angular

In Angular I have a list of objects in form of `Observable` that I fetch from a `service` which is being displayed in a `ngFor`. Now I'm filtering this with respect to a value from a select dropdown by passing the list to a `Pipe` and fetching it back. But it doesn't update in HTML although the Pipe's `transform` function is executed. Any help would be appreciated.

**component.ts**

```
providers: [CompanyPipe]
export class CommonTableComponent implements {
constructor(private companyPipe: CompanyPipe){ }
data: any[] = [];
this.data = this.companyPipe.transform(this.data, object.value);
}
```

**component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of data">
 <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

**pipe**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'company'
})
export class CompanyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  company: any[];

  constructor(private detailsService: DetailsService) {}

  transform(value: any[], param?: number): any[] {
    if (param === undefined) {
      return value;
    }

    for (const item of value) {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:triple-equals
      if (item.comp_id == param) {
        this.company.push(item);
      }
    }
    if (this.company.length < 10) {
      // this.detailsService.flag = false;
    }
    return this.company;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: Please post the entire component.ts

Comment: Could you show us the pipe code ?

Comment: posted the code of html, component and Pipe. If anything else is needed do mention it

Answer (score 0):

This is not how pipes should be used if your intention is to filter dyanmic data

```
this.data = this.companyPipe.transform(this.data, object.value)
```

The above line will only filter the item when the component loads(i.e when the constructor runs) any event after that like selection from dropdown won't make the data go into the filter

instead try this

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of data | company">
 <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

In this way it will dynamically filter with the pipe

Comment: I have tried that but the problem is I have a total of 4 dropdowns to filter, all of them will be in AND condition. But the moment the list is filtered from a small list to a larger one, the Pipe fails. That is why I opted for this approach

Comment: Then subscribe to your dropdown change event and call your pipe there

Comment: could you provide some specifics regarding the code? As such I'm firing a function on every change of dropdown and calling the Pipe from the compoenent, locally.

Comment: Could you update your question indication how are you doing it now clearly?